# bundle product with fixed price and special price percent does not work with catalogue price rules

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product, catalog-price-rules

I have a bundle product with the following set:

- fixed price of $300
- special price 90%

When I create a catalogue price rule of 10% off all products I would expect the product price to be less than $270 (but it is not) - the special price of the bundle and the catalogue price rule discount.

Is this a bug in magento? and if so is there anyway to fix this or setup my price rule differently?

**EDIT**

In fact this seems to be a wider issue where catalogue price rules do not apply to any special prices. I guess this is something to do with catalogue price rules applying to "percentage of the original price".

Can I setup magento's config to calculate both special price and catalogue price rule across all product types?

Comment: I believe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120342/catalog-price-rules-applied-to-special-price/26801550#26801550 solves this issue on Magento 1.9